# Why does a space at the end of a value disappear when selecting an item from a datalist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I ran into a curious issue where the space at the end of a value disappears, when using a datalist. It left me wondering why. (I am using google chrome)

I can make sure that the space at the end will be included in
    the end result by assigning it to a value attribute, instead of inbetween the `<option>` and `</option>` tags. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9hvyt6c/1/) that works.

1. **Why does the value in input (#datalist-input) remove the space at
       the end when selecting the value from the datalist?**
2. **Should I use the space inbetween the `<option>` and `</option>` tags at all? If so, what for. If not why not and why isn't the `<option>` tag selfclosing only if this is the case?**

**JSFiddle link, that removes the space:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9hvyt6c/)

**html**

```
<h3>The disappearing of a space at the end of a line</h3>
<input id="input" type="text" value="Space at the end " disabled="true">
<datalist id="datalist"></datalist>
<input id="datalist-input" list="datalist">
<h6>(select the only option in the datalist and click somewhere to trigger the script)</h6>
```

**javascript/jQuery**

```
let originalInput = $("#input").val();
$("#datalist").append(`<option>${originalInput}</option>`);
$("#datalist-input").change(function () {
    let datalistText = $("#datalist-input").val();
    if(datalistText !== originalInput) {
        alert(`The original value: "${originalInput}" is not equal to: "${datalistText}"`);
    } else {
        alert(`The original value: "${originalInput}" is equal to: "${datalistText}"`);
    }
}); // end change
```

Comment: @adeneo changed the datalist tag to html-select. Suppose that would be more accurate :).

Comment: reason you are not using value in datalist? Leading/trailing whitespace in html tags is ignored.

Comment: @epascarello https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp seems to suggest that you don't have to use the value tag. The question is about why innerText is being treated differently from a value. And if we should use the innerText at all or treat the option tag as a self-closing one without innerText.

Comment: But when you care about whitespace, you need to use the value attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens any time you have leading or trailing whitespace in the text of an option, and no value attribute.

The text of the option is used as the value, and whitespace is trimmed off.

This behaviour is specified in the HTML [specification](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-option-element.html#dom-option-text)

> The `value` attribute provides a value for element.
>   The value of an
>   option element is the value of the value content attribute, if there
>   is one, or, if there is not, the value of the element's `text` IDL
>   attribute.

Note that it just says the value is the same as the "text IDL" if no value is set, but for options the "text IDL" is specified as follows

> ***option . text***
>   Same as textContent, **except that spaces are collapsed**.

It specifically says that spaces are collapsed when getting the "text IDL" that is used to set the value attribute if no such attribute is already set on the element, so this is the expected behaviour.

Here's an example showing the difference between letting the text be used as the value, and specifically adding a value attribute :

```js
var t1 = $('#test1 option').get(0),
    t2 = $('#test2 option').get(0);
    
console.log( t1.value, t1.value.length );             // length === 10
console.log( t1.textContent, t1.textContent.length ); // length === 12

console.log( t2.value, t2.value.length );             // length === 22
console.log( t2.textContent, t2.textContent.length ); // length === 22

/*
    The option where the text is converted to a value property has a difference in length, the whitespace is trimmed.
    
    The option whith a value attribute, where the text isn't used for the value property, keeps the whitespace, and the length is the same
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test1">
  <option> has spaces </option>
</select>

<select id="test2">
  <option value=" has spaces and value "> has spaces and value </option>
</select>
```

The solution in this case would be to add a value

```
$("#datalist").append(`<option value="${originalInput}">`);
```

Comment: Interesting. W3C seems to contradict itself: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp suggest in a note that you can use the option tag without using any attributes. I suppose this is only partially true then. I would consider question 1 answered.

Comment: However if I use a datalist your code would output 2 values in the dropdown list in Chrome (in a datalist, not select); https://jsfiddle.net/b9hvyt6c/3/ . That leaves the question, should we use the textContent of the option tags or would it be much better to always use a value attribute and no textContent at all and basically treat the option tag as a selfclosing one?

Comment: You **can** use an option tag without a value attribute, but as the spec says, spaces will be collapsed when doing so. You are right, when using both a value and text, they are both displayed in the datalist, meaning you should use one or the other. The [specs for datalist](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element) does show both text or value as valid, but again, using text only the spaces will be trimmed when converted to a value.