# How to ignore trailing white spaces in text input when comparing to datalist options?

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, html-datalist

I am using AJAX to pull potential matching results from the server and append the options to the datalist on the search bar on every key-up event. The problem is if the user adds trailing white spaces, the datalist collapses and doesn't show the matching results. How can I force the datalist to remain open if there is a matching results with additional trailing white spaces?

The behavior I describe is illustrated in this [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9hvyt6c/) (not mine, pulled from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242561/why-does-a-space-at-the-end-of-a-value-disappear-when-selecting-an-item-from-a-d))

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('load', function(){
    var search_input = $("#listing-search-bar")

    if (search_input) {
     search_input.keyup(function(el){
      autocomplete(el);
     });
    };

    function autocomplete(el) {
      var input = el.target;
      var min_chars = 0;
      if (input.value.length > min_chars) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "/listings/search",
          data: {"query" : input.value},
          dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(response) {
          // Add catch for if request failed
          response.forEach( function(city) {
            console.log(city)
            if (!$(`#cities option[value="${city}"]`).length) {
              $("#cities").append(`<option value="${city}"></option>`);
            };
          });
        });
      };
    };
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
 <%= form_with url: search_listings_path, method: :get, local: true, id: "listing-search-bar" do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :query, placeholder: "Search a city...", list: "cities" %>
      <datalist id="cities"></datalist>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

datalist options have some attribute like value, if you set value then it will open the drop-down with space. For example you can check following code

```
let originalInput = $("#input").val();
$("#datalist").append(`<option value=${originalInput}>${originalInput}</option>`);
$("#datalist-input").change(function(){
if(datalistText !== originalInput){
    alert(`The original value: "${originalInput}" is not equal to: "${datalistText}"`);
}else{
  alert(`The original value: "${originalInput}" is equal to: "${datalistText}"`);
}}); // end change
```